# Spring Boot with Maven Install vs Eclipse Export WAR

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I hardly use Maven.The only time for me to use it is for maintaining my web app dependencies.

Now I started to develop web app using Spring Boot. I notice when I run `Maven install`, a WAR file will be created in the target folder. Then I export WAR using `File > Export` on my STS IDE and compare the two wars. The size of the 2 files are different. How can this be ? Also, the WAR file created from Maven runs fine on standalone Tomcat 7 while the exported war from Eclipse (STS) doesn't.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Maybe export from STS has provided jars, can you check this??

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonable to assume that WTP (File > Export > Web etc) would produce a different WAR file from the maven build. Maven build may have plugins applied to the build to produce the desired WAR file. Check your POM file carefully and check if there are any maven plugins used in the build.
Now, I don't exactly know how Eclipse WTP component produces their WAR file (Export WAR file is not from STS - it's Eclipse WebToolsProject) from the project. There might be options in the export wizard to play around with or some configuration file in your project. You'd better off asking that on the Eclipse forum: https://eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=88
Hope this helps.